# ChromeDriver 2.29 Unable to set automatic downloads to Allow by default

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

After upgrading to ChromeDriver 2.29, the default value for 'Automatic Downloads 'localhost:9000' is set to 'Ask'. Whenever my tests clicks on a link which invokes a download, the Save As windows dialog opens up. Previously it would download silently to the default Downloads folder of Chrome.

How do I change this setting's default value to 'Allow' in chromedriver (not chrome)?

I've tried using the chrome.switches but they didn't work:

```
chrome.switches=--disable-extensions,--disable-infobars,--allow-insecure-localhost,--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection
```

The default setting in Chrome is 'Allow' for all sites.
'http://localhost:9000' has also been added to Exceptions list.

[image]

Comment: For reference, there is a long chain of things people have tried here: https://github.com/TheBrainFamily/chimpy/issues/108 I'm unsure if the same version is used.

Answer (score 1):

You can set default download location using capabilities. It will download the file to that folder, it won't give any pop up's

Just try with below line of code

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
String downloadPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "\\Downloads";

HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadPath);
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", "true");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<>();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--test-type");

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,chromeOptionsMap);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
```

Let me know if you face any issue

Comment: I don't want to use DesiredCapabilities/Chrome Options. Instead use it as a Chrome Switch or via command-line argument.

Comment: what is the difference if you use capabilities

Comment: The Test Automation Framework is built using Serenity BDD framework which handles ChromeDriver invocation automatically. We can pass the 'chrome.switches' in a property file or via command-line. Therefore I was requesting for an approach that does not involve using DesiredCapabilities.